# Including new lines in PHP preg_replace function

Tags: php, regex, newline

I'm trying to match a string that may appear over multiple lines. It starts and ends with a specific string:

```
{a}some string
can be multiple lines
{/a}
```

Can I grab everything between `{a}` and `{/a}` with a regex? It seems the . doesn't match new lines, but I've tried the following with no luck:

```
$template = preg_replace( $'/\{a\}([.\n]+)\{\/a\}/', 'X', $template, -1, $count );
echo $count; // prints 0
```

It matches . or \n when they're on their own, but not together!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the [`s` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
$template = preg_replace( $'/\{a\}([.\n]+)\{\/a\}/s', 'X', $template, -1, $count );
//                                                ^
echo $count;
```

Comment: Awesome, I knew it would be something simple like that!

Comment: Also, I just found that this info IS on the PHP website, even though I've never found it before when looking... http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 7):

I think you've got more problems than just the dot not matching newlines, but let me start with a formatting recommendation.  You can use just about any punctuation character as the regex delimiter, not just the slash ('/').  If you use another character, you won't have to escape slashes within the regex.  I understand '%' is popular among PHPers; that would make your pattern argument:

```
'%\{a\}([.\n]+)\{/a\}%'
```

Now, the reason that regex didn't work as you intended is because the dot loses its special meaning when it appears inside a character class (the square brackets)--so `[.\n]` just matches a dot or a linefeed.  What you were looking for was `(?:.|\n)`, but I would have recommended matching the carriage-return as well as the linefeed:

```
'%\{a\}((?:.|[\r\n])+)\{/a\}%'
```

That's because the word "newline" can refer to the Unix-style "\n", Windows-style "\r\n", or older-Mac-style "\r".  Any given web page may contain any of those or a mixture of two or more styles; a mix of "\n" and "\r\n" is very common.  But with /s mode (also known as single-line or DOTALL mode), you don't need to worry about that:

```
'%\{a\}(.+)\{/a\}%s'
```

However, there's another problem with the original regex that's still present in this one: the `+` is greedy.  That means, if there's more than one `{a}...{/a}` sequence in the text, the first time your regex is applied it will match all of them, from the first `{a}` to the last `{/a}`.  The simplest way to fix that is to make the `+` ungreedy (a.k.a, "lazy" or "reluctant") by appending a question mark:

```
'%\{a\}(.+?)\{/a\}%s'
```

Finally, I don't know what to make of the '$' before the opening quote of your pattern argument.  I don't do PHP, but that looks like a syntax error to me.  If someone could educate me in this matter, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Oh, that must be a typo - I was origially using a variable there and replaced it with a string for this example.

Comment: This was a great explanation.  Cheers for this.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html:

> "The dot matches a single character,
>   without caring what that character is.
>   The only exception are newline
>   characters."

you will need to add a trailing /s flag to your expression.