# Using PHP to replace a frequently-changing string between two html tags

Tags: php, html, regex, replace, reverse-proxy

I'm running a reverse proxy on an `Apache` server. Using `PHP`, I'm trying to replace a string in the html of one of the pages being proxied with another string.

I added the following line to the `apache2.conf` in order to do the filtering:

```
ExtFilterDefine proxyfilter mode=output cmd="/usr/bin/php proxyfilter.php"
```

Here is the `proxyfilter.php` file referenced above that is doing the filtering:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('php://stdin');

//solution 1 fails
$start=strpos($html,"<div id="id1" class="class1" >");
$end=strpos($html,"</div>");
$html=substr($html,0,$start+strlen('<div id="id1" class="class1" >') . "new-string" . substr($html,$end);

//solution 2 fails
$html = preg_replace('/<div id="id1" class="class1" >(.*?)<\/div>/', '<div id="id1" class="class1" >"new-string"</div>', $html);

file_put_contents('php://stdout', $html);
?>
```

The actual `HTML` that needs to be filtered (as it appears when you view the page in a browser and do view source) looks like:

```
<div id="id1" class="class1" >
 string-to-be-replaced     </div>
```

I'm running into two problems:

1. The string I am trying to replace changes frequently.
2. The string is located in between two `<div>` tags but there's also a bunch of extra spaces and a line break right before/after the string inside the `<div>` tags.

Looking at similar questions on Google & StackOverflow I was able to deduce two possible ways of going about this:

1. Using `preg_replace` and `regex` to search for the unique `<div>` tag and then use wildcards for the text that needs to be replaced- but from what I understand this won't work because of the line break (see solution 1 above in `proxyfilter.php`) and I'm not entirely familiar with `regex`.
2. Using `substr` or another similar function to search for the unique `<div>` tag and then just replace everything inside the tags rather than trying to use `regex` and wildcards (see solution 2 above in `proxyfilter.php`). I believe this solution is failing because it's just searching a predefined string where as I am searching within an `HTML` document and I'm not entirely sure how to bridge the gap there, if that makes sense.

I know the `proxyfilter.php` itself is working because I am able to successfully replace static strings found in the `html` using `str_replace`. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this successfully would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your desired out put from the input so that we can help you easly

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need the `s` modifier.

See [Including new lines in PHP preg_replace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695633/including-new-lines-in-php-preg-replace-function)

So your code would be

```
$html = preg_replace('/<div id="id1" class="class1" >(.*?)<\/div>/s', '<div id="id1" class="class1" >"new-string"</div>', $html);
```